# Reactive Spring security kerberos compatible with Spring 5

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-kerberos

I'm writing an application using Spring 5 reactive stack. Currently, we are using spring-security-kerberos-core 1.1 along with Spring 4 artifacts. Wondering when writing things in Spring 5 along with reactive stack, is there any reactive library available for kerberos-core?